# Integration testing calls with simulated delays

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I'm testing an asp.net Core 2.2 WebApi backend which uses EF Core for data persistance.

The solution is arquitected using CLEAN arquitecture with a repository/service pattern making every component individually testable.

My integration tests (using XUnit and EF Core in-memory database) need to test the following cases:

1. User makes a request and instantly makes another identical request.
2. User makes a request and 15 seconds later, makes another identical request.
3. User makes a request and 30 seconds later, makes another identical request.

Each of these cases have about 5 variants each. Right now, I'm using a `Thread.Sleep(x)` call in between each of the calls to simulate this delay. This, of course, means that my integration tests take *ages* to complete. The delays are used in order for the repository layer to save a `DateTime.UtcNow` value when each of the calls is made; the value of which is used by the Service layer to perform some business-logic decisions.

What I'm wondering, is whether there is a way of 'simulating' these delays using the testing framework, removing the need for the tests to actually wait this time, and *tricking* the repository layer into using a `DateTime.UtcNow` value which is incremented by `x`.

Thanks you!

Comment: Abstract the `DateTime` access behind some interface `interface IClock { DateTime UtcNow { get; }}` That can be mocked to behave as desired when testing.

Comment: It depends on what the time frame means. If you're just wondering what happens at some later point in the future, then @Nkosi is right: you can just mock out the clock, and literally set the time to the future time. However, it's probably more likely that you're looking a concurrency or concurrency-like type situations here, and in that case, you literally need to space out the calls in realtime. As such, you either accept the longer test times or move it into a different (generally manual) testing layer.

Comment: For example, it might be run by an actual UAT person. Test times aren't a big deal in that scenario, per se. It's only *really* problematic when it's part of your CI pipeline.

Comment: @Nkosi, that's a great idea! Post it as an answer if you'd like me to set it as accepted.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, we ARE looking at concurrency situations/behaviors, but because of how everything is structured, testing concurrent calls/idempotency issues are handled in "case 1", which doesn't add testing time. The rest of the tests handle idempotency issues but somewhat differently and these would be compatible with the proposed DateTime abstraction solution.
And yes, the issue arises with our CI/CD pipelines. I have a policy where any PR must first pass a Testing Pipeline, which really slows things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract the `DateTime` access behind some interface

```
public interface IDateTime { 
    DateTime UtcNow { get; }

    //...other members as needed. eg: DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

That can be mocked to behave as desired when testing.

The production implementation would simple wrap the actual `DateTime`

```
public class DefaultClock : IDateTime {
    public DateTime UtcNow => DateTime.UtcNow;

    //...
}
```

and registered with your DI container

```
service.AddSingleton<IDateTime, DefaultClock>();
```

When testing, the abstraction can be mocked as needed;

```
//Arrange
DateTime time;
DatTime.TryParse("2009-05-01 12:00:00", out time);

var mock = new Mock<IDateTime>(); //USING MOQ

mock.SetupSequence(_ => _.UtcNow)
    .Returns(time);                 //first call
    .Returns(time.AddSeconds(15))   //second call
    .Returns(time.AddSeconds(30));  //third call

IDateTime clock = mock.Object;

//...inject clock into subject under test
```

Comment: Also consider the NodaTime library, which was basically made for this and a ton of other deficiencies in the CLR types.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks, I'll also look into NodaTime, but right now I'm more comfortable adding a custom interface that I control fully rather than adding another dependency to the solution. Are there any "hidden" advantages to relying on NodaTime rather than implementing a custom interface as-per the answer above?

Comment: Depends on the needs of your app. It's far more capable of handling i18n needs than the CLR types. You can do actual calendar math, and work with actual timezones instead of just offsets, where things like DST can bite you hard.